# Eclipse remote debugging not working, step over, step into, step return disabled

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

I have (I think) managed to get Tomcat running in debug mode externally to Eclipse:

[image: tomcat startup]

But when I try to debug my project from within Eclipse, the step into, step over, and step return buttons are greyed out, and also, breakpoints are not observed; all I have is a disconnect button:

[image: all debugging buttons disabled]

Basically, the project in Eclipse starts, but other than that, I cannot debug it.

What am I doing wrong?  I'm running Eclipse Photon 4.8.0, Tomcat 9.0.10.

Many thanks in advance.

Edit:
When I run Tomcat in Eclipse in debug mode the program suspends at the first breakpoint and debugging functionality is available:

[image: debugging when running Tomcat in debug mode inside Eclipse]

Comment: Those buttons are only enabled when a thread is suspended by at a breakpoint - all your threads are Running.

Comment: I have breakpoints set. When I run Tomcat in debug mode inside Eclipse, the breakpoint is reached as expected, the program is suspended and debugging functionality is available: 


  https://i.stack.imgur.com/0MWHV.png